# Can we alter image source from typescript code?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, dom

I am starting with simple Typescript(.ts)+HTML(.js)  code for practice. 
In HTML page I have below tag to display certain image :

```html
<img id="myimage" src='images/samsung_edge_silver.jpg' height="250px">
<div><b><span id="Name"></b></div>
```

Now I have ts file to alter fields in this code.
I can change the value of span field Name using :

```
document.getElementById("pName").innerHTML = productName;
```

But is there any way I can alter the value of source URL for myimage.

I read a few answers, people are giving an answer for angular mostly. 
But this is pure typescript+html. 
How do we assign a new value to image source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do this:

`(document.getElementById('test') as HTMLImageElement).src = 'http://www.image.com';`

The reason for this is that `document.getElementById('id')` will return an HTMlElement and not all HTMLElement have `src` property.

Comment: Worked a treat...! Thank you. Did not knew these were two different things.

Answer (score 2):

You can set it like this.

```
document.getElementById('myimage').src = 'http://yourImagePathHere';
```

Checkout the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/imjaydeep/1s7jhwub/8/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  It is not working though. We get "[ts] Property 'src' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'. [2339]" error if we use above solution.

Comment: seems image id was mismatched.. here is the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/imjaydeep/1s7jhwub/8/ check it out..

Comment: I know that every valid javascript code is a valid typescript code.  But this is not getting compiled using ts version 3.4.5. Still getting above mentioned error.

Comment: i have tested it in fiddle with typescript as well and it worked. if you are yet to get the answer can you create a fiddle in which it can be reproduced.

Comment: Answer given by @riazosama worked. apparently getElementById returns HTMIElement and not HTMLElement.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using angular, you can do something like this:

HTML:

```
<img [src]="mySource">
```

Typescript:

```
mySource = "/maybeAssets/default.png";

changeSourceImage() {
   this.mySource = "/maybeAssets/funnyCats.png"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. As I mentioned I am not using angular. its simple typescript file. I do understand that with angular it is very easy to modify the properties of any HTML element. I am deliberately avoiding using angular here.

Comment: @VDevD I didn't notice that. For full typescript solutions, you already have the answer for that :D